# Как проверить в Postman работу паттерна PRG (посмотреть места контроллера, где побывал запрос)

Tags: java, spring, postman

Есть следующий контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String create(@RequestParam("name") name) {
        // registration logic
        return "redirect:message?message=Created";
    }

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String message(@RequestParam("message") String message, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "message.html";
    }
}
```

Собственно message.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HW3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p th:if="${message != null}" th:text="${message}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Отправляя в postman post запрос, я вижу, что была показана страница message.html, то есть все отработало верно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: могу ли я более детально посмотреть в postman "путь" в контроллере. То есть могу ли я цепочку мест, куда попал запрос от момента входа в контроллер и до самого конца (скажем что-то похожее client -> /create -> /message -> client)

P. S. не предлагайте пожалуйста дебаггер, я в курсе, что так можно. Меня интересует конкретно функциональность Postman

Comment: Не совсем оно, но редиректы отключить можно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023744/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, благодарю вас за ответ, но это не то, что мне нужно. Отключив редирект, постман просто останавливается на /create в моем случае и просто показывает 302 found.

Comment: Я немного погуглил и, судя по всему, такой фичи в Postman нет. Единственное, что в голову приходит - писать в самом Postman тесты, в которых редиректы вручную обрабатывать